# Issue with key being stuck down on Dell Inspiron 2 in 1

Tags: keyboard, hardware-failure, dell-inspiron

Recently on my laptop, the down volume key has been spammed down when it's not being pressed. I'm running Debian 7, but I've confirmed it's not a software issue. Whenever I boot I can see [^26] in the boot terminal for lines upon lines while it's booting. I'm able to stop it by opening a terminal and typing xinput float keyboardID, and then I can continue using a USB keyboard, but this doesn't actually solve the problem. I realized it wasn't a software issue when I booted into a live USB and the same issue occured. I went ahead and opened my case and disconnected my keyboard from the motherboard, tested it and made sure it was completely disconnected, but it still thought the key was being pressed, even when there was no keyboard attached. I found [this](http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3518/t/19330635) saying it was a problem with the multimedia panel being separate from the keyboard, but found no mention of a multimedia panel anywhere in the laptop's service manual. The exact model is a Dell Inspiron 7 7773. I reconnected my keyboard ribbon but the problem still exists, and I can't figure out what I can do to solve it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find a teardown of your exact model but similar models have hardware volume keys somewhere. This gentleman found that the separate cable of these keys was pinched:

http://en.community.dell.com/support-forums/laptop/f/3517/t/19635603

Since these kinds of hardware panels mostly just send keystrokes to tell the OS to change the volume, rather than directly controlling the hardware, this could very well be where the keystrokes keep coming from.